# Differential Equations; A prerequisite to Differential Geometry?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Is thorough knowledge in ODEs/PDEs and solution techniques to be considered a prerequisite to the study of Differential Geometry (Specifically Riemannian Geometry)?

If not, how would one describe the relation between the subjects?

Comment: It would depend on what kind of differential geometry interests you, but the basic definitions don't require a thorough knowledge, no, depending on how you define thorough. I managed with a very, very basic knowledge. But if you want to do advanced stuff, it will of course be important, although you can probably learn that on the fly.

There are no "hard prerequisites" in real life, so a general tip for learning is just to find something you like and then backtrack when needed, or blackbox some things. Be careful of blaxbocking too much too early though.

Comment: No sure but Analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (manifolds, differential forms, etc...) seem more important the ODE/PDE knowledge.

Comment: @Tedar I like your approach. BTW Iv'e been black-boxing my way around Riemannian Geometry for quite some time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More urgently than a thorough knowledge of ODE's or PDE's is thorough knowledge of linear algebra, vector calculus, duality and tensor product to have a good intuitive platform to understand modern geometry.

Comment: see the Q. & the A. of the post [ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635375/another-vector-bundles-over-of-a-riemannian-manifold ] to get an idea

Comment: I believe I am missing duality and tensor product. Any recommended resources?

Comment: a modern portal -definitely- is [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_algebra ]

Comment: i have a bilingual effort at [ https://www.facebook.com/AlgebraMultilineal ]

Comment: But what about Geometry itself?! I remember when I was reading D.J.Struik's [book](https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Classical-Differential-Geometry-Mathematics/dp/0486656098), the author referred us to some concepts in non-Euclidean Geometry(Projective, Affine, Hyperbolic etc) a few times, though I couldn't really see the connection.

Comment: @AshkanRanjbar  those sciences are well grasped after that algebra is acquainted

Answer (score 4):

You need DEs to *do* differential geometry, like solve geodesic equations, but I do not think you need DEs at all to understand differential geometry. If anything you need differential geometry to understand DEs properly (vector fields on manfolds etc), though you do not really need DG to *do* DEs. As @janmarqz said the main formal prerequisites for DG is linear algebra & vector calculus (and of course solid background in calculus). A basic grasp of topology does not hurt though. However, I think the most important thing is just mental visualization. It also helps to have texts with good illustrations.